# How to calculate residual sum of squares?

Tags: regression

$Y_i = a + bX_i + u_i$

I found the estimates of a and b from this simple regression model by using some given facts below.

$\sum X_i=40, \sum y_i=60, \sum X_i^2=200, \sum y_i^2=2460,\sum X_iy_i=240, n=20$

From these information, I calculated estimates of $a$ and $b$:

$\hat{a}= 1, \hat{b}= 1$

And by using these results, I want to calculate the residual sum of squares, $\sum \hat{u_i}^2$.

(My final goal is to get the estimate of var(ui), which is $\frac{1}{n-2}\sum \hat{u_i}^2$)

Can you help me calculate $\sum \hat{u_i}^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You'll just expand the term and replace what you've:
$$\begin{align}\sum u_i^2&=\sum{(y_i-a-bx_i)^2}\\&=\sum y_i^2+a^2n+b^2\sum x_i^2-2\left(b\sum x_iy_i+ab\sum x_i+a\sum y_i\right)\end{align}$$
Note: check your $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ (and best to share them here for inspection) because I couldn't reproduce your results (it might be my mistake).